# How do I run a GPU VM from Cloud Run?

Tags: gpu, virtual-machine, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-compute-engine

I want to run a quick GPU ML process from Cloud Run. I can't use Anthos (too expensive) nor Batch (too slow) but can I somehow have Cloud Run call a GPU enabled Compute Engine VM? And how would the VM scale?

Comment: `can I somehow have Cloud Run call a GPU enabled Compute Engine VM`. Yes, you can but why use Cloud Run, which would just be a middleman? Just publish the API from the VM. To enable autoscaling you would need to set up a load balancer, Managed Instance Group, and autoscaling.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

While it is possible to use Cloud Run to call a GPU-enabled Compute Engine VM, it may be more efficient to publish the API from the VM directly. To enable autoscaling, you would need to set up a load balancer, Managed Instance Group, and autoscaling. This approach can simplify management and reduce costs by eliminating the need for a middleman.

Comment: It seems Cloud Run is cheap spot instance, what you really get is variable over time, whereas VM are long term more stable stuff. On top of that I believe most servers have a physical limitation when provisioning GPU, not only the region of the datacenter, but also the rack must have a very close GPU. Sometimes datacenter even need custom GPU PCIE connector hardware to be able to scale certain configuration (as GPU are physically much complex to integrate rather than CPU cores) and it needs air cooling flow. On top of that only few GPU model have a VM like driver bios (special Nvidia licenses)